# Flowable BPMN with DMN using Java API

Tags: java, flowable

I am new to Flowable and exploring its features by using Flowable JAVA API.

Have managed to design a bpmn flow and execute it using ProcessEngine of flowable-engine java library from Flowable.

```
  <groupId>org.flowable</groupId>
  <artifactId>flowable-engine</artifactId>
  <version>6.7.0</version>
```

Later, I managed to create a Decision table(*.dmn.xml) and also referenced it to a business process flow(*.bpmn.xml) file by following reference link mentioned below

https://flowable.com/open-source/docs/dmn/ch06-DMN-Introduction/

Please let me know how do I use dmn with bpmn using Flowable JAVA API.

Answer (score 0):

You can first deploy the dmn into the dmn engine.
Then you can have a bpmn with a Decision Task(a service task with type as dmn).
This will internally call the dmn engine to evaluate the result.
You can refer this [Flowable BPMN DmnActivityBehavior](https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/blob/main/modules/flowable-engine/src/main/java/org/flowable/engine/impl/bpmn/behavior/DmnActivityBehavior.java) to check the java api calling from bpmn to dmn.

Answer (score 0):

All we got to do is to make process engine aware of the DMN resource xml and DMNEngineConfigurator. Below snippet for reference

```
private static void deployProcess(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
    Deployment deployment = repositoryService.createDeployment()
            .addClasspathResource("LoanRequest.bpmn20.xml")
            .addClasspathResource("EvaluateLoanCreate.dmn.xml")
            .deploy();
}

    private static DmnEngineConfigurator getDMNEngineConfigurator(){
    DmnEngineConfiguration dmnEngineConfiguration = new DmnEngineConfiguration()
            .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/C:/user/Program Files/h2-2019-03-13/test;SCHEMA=flowabledemo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")
            .setJdbcUsername("user")
            .setJdbcPassword("Password")
            .setJdbcDriver("org.h2.Driver")
            .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE);
    DmnEngineConfigurator dmnEngineConfigurator = new DmnEngineConfigurator()
            .setDmnEngineConfiguration(dmnEngineConfiguration);


    return dmnEngineConfigurator;
}

ProcessEngineConfiguration cfg = (ProcessEngineConfiguration) new StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration().setConfigurators(Arrays.asList(getDMNEngineConfigurator()));
```